# Indoor Navigation without Beacons

Tags: ios, bluetooth, navigation, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

currently i'am working on a university project where i want to create a smartphone indoor navigation solution without beacons. Is there any possible way of combining the map of the area with sensors of the smartphone to get a good accuracy? When I did research the most of the solutions rely on BLE Beacons, some on other technologies.

I only saw one company called mapsted which just rely on their algorithm. But i cannot mind how this should work. Like i thought indoor positioning always need something (e.g. beacon) to determine the smartphones location via triangulation.

If anyone has some thoughts on this topic, thank you :)

Comment: First the accuracy of your known starting point will be a problem. How will you detect exactly where in the building the person is?  Second using inertial sensors will have quite large error due to the way the person is holding the phone and their walking gait etc. I think these errors will quickly overwhelm the accuracy of the result. Apple's indoor mapping framework uses triangulation of known wifi signals. As long as you have mapped the space with their tool you can include indoor maps in your app without any additional hardware or being connected to a wifi network

Comment: Hi, so you mean if i map my space with apples framework and add data about the wifi stations i could do positioning and routing?

Comment: Apple provides an indoor mapping tool that you use to survey the space.  You can then include the survey data in your app.  Watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/241 and https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/245

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on Indoor Positioning without Beacons but don't have any idea to plot it on Map or floorplan. If you get any solution just let me know. You can search out about the openstreetmaps , Mapbox and openlayers where u can create indoor map and use it for ploting.

Comment: this isn't answer and should be added as comment (author asking for favor, not answering the question)

Answer (score 0):

Use GeoJson and Openlayers to create your indoor map in openstreetmaps so that you get the coordinates and you can plot person with the help of coordinates.

You can use [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) which help you for geofencing and other functionality.